# Redirects and Subdirectory migration to Root Directory

Tags: migration

I'm trying to find the most efficient way possible to help a client replace an old site with a new site. It's riddling with plug-in issues and there's been several developers involved before me who apparently couldn't figure this out.

Seems like it should be simple, but now I'm lost in the rabbit hole because of what the client is asking about redirects. Obviously, because the old site is  we want to redirect the old site links floating around the net to the new site but i'm not quite sure on the path to take....

The new site has been built in a subfolder, so the url is sitename.org/new

I want to replace the old site at www.sitename.org with the new site so that the /new is not longer in the url. I know this involves removing the old site files and replacing them with the new site files in the root directory. I just don't want to waste time doing anything unnecessary to straight this client's issue out.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following:

- Move all old files in the root dir to a special folder (i.e. "_old")
- Login to the new site in subdir and remove the subdir from the `Wordpress` and `Site Adress` (so remove `sitename.org/new` and enter `sitename.org`)
- Using FTP or your hosts file manager, move all files from the subdir "new" to the root
- Now you can login to the new site in the root dir
- Flush / Resave permalinks
- Search and Replace the subdir URL with the root URL inside the wp-database (using one of many plugins, i.e "Better Search and Replace", dont update the GUIDs)
- Add rewrite rules per htaccess or per wp plugin (i.e. "All 404 Redirect to Homepage")
- Reset caching and test the site to see if everything is ok

But before anything, create backups!